# Mapping random sample

Tags: matlab, dataset, random

I have a slight problem, I cant reverse the singular value decompisition from my process but I was wondering if I can map data beforehand.

One of my datasets is named fulldata. I apply svds to this data like so:

```
%% dimensionality reduction 
columns = 6
[U,S,V]=svds(fulldata,columns);
```

I then randomly pick 1000 rows from the dataset:

```
rows = 1000;
columns = 6;

%# pick random rows
indX = randperm( size(fulldata,1) );
indX = indX(1:rows);

%# pick random columns
indY = indY(1:columns);

%# filter data
data = U(indX,indY);
```

I need to find a way in which I can tell which 1000 rows it picked from the fulldata? Maybe output data from 1 - 1000 with the row number from fulldata. Does anyone know a way in which it can be done?

Comment: Doesn't `indX` already contain that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are almost there:

```
rows = 1000;
indX = randperm( size(fulldata,1) );
indX = indX(1:rows);

dataSample = fulldata(indX, :);
```

dataSample will now contain all rows of fulldata specified in indX.

Comment: Ahh im such a donkey so I am! It was because indX was outputing it along the columns 1 - 1000 columns not down the way (rows) is there a way to get indX to store it down the rows rather than along the columns? Thanks H.Muster!

Comment: Sure. Just use `indX = indX(1:rows)';` (Note the apostroph.)